# Load model from Keras and investigate the details

Tags: keras

I'm using Keras to fit a function, and I'm new to Keras.
With a very simple network, the Keras can fit my function very well, I just want to know what the function is and try to understand why it works very well. But the "predict" function hide the details.

Here is the code I create the network:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

LABEL_COLUMN = "shat"
BATCH_SIZE = 16
EPOCHS = 20

trainfilePath = "F:\\PyworkingFolder\\WWSHat\\_Data\\alpha0train.csv"
testfilePath = "F:\\PyworkingFolder\\WWSHat\\_Data\\alpha0test.csv"

with open(trainfilePath, encoding='utf-8') as txtContent:
    trainArray = np.loadtxt(txtContent, delimiter=",")

with open(testfilePath, encoding='utf-8') as txtContent:
    testArray = np.loadtxt(txtContent, delimiter=",")

trainSample = trainArray[:, 0:14]
trainLable = trainArray[:, 14]
testSample = testArray[:, 0:14]
testLable = testArray[:, 14]

model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Dense(14, activation='relu', input_shape=[14]),
    keras.layers.Dense(15, activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dense(1)
])

optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(0.001)
# optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adadelta(lr=1.0, rho=0.95, epsilon=None, decay=0.0)
model.compile(loss='mse',
              optimizer=optimizer,
              metrics=['mae', 'mse'])

model.summary()
history = model.fit(trainSample, trainLable, epochs=EPOCHS, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)
model.evaluate(testSample, testLable, verbose=1)
model.save("F:\\PyworkingFolder\\WWSHat\\_Data\\alpha0.h5")
```

What I understand is:
the layers are weight matrices and basis matrices, it works as

out=max(0, weight * input + basis)

After some search, I find I can read the .h5 file using

```
import h5py
import numpy as np

FILENAME = "F:\\PyworkingFolder\\WWSHat\\_Data\\alpha0.h5"

with h5py.File(FILENAME, 'r') as f:
    dense_1 = f['/model_weights/dense_1/dense_1']
    dense_1_bias = dense_1['bias:0'][:]
    dense_1_kernel = dense_1['kernel:0'][:]

    dense_2 = f['/model_weights/dense_2/dense_2']
    dense_2_bias = dense_2['bias:0'][:]
    dense_2_kernel = dense_2['kernel:0'][:]

# print("Weight matrix 1:\n")
# print(dense_1_kernel)

# print("Basis matrix 1:\n")
# print(dense_1_bias)

# print("Weight matrix 2:\n")
# print(dense_2_kernel)

# print("Basis matrix 2:\n")
# print(dense_2_bias)


def layer_output(v, kernel, bias):
    return np.dot(v, kernel) + bias


reluFunction = np.vectorize(lambda x: x if x >= 0.0 else 0.0)

testV = np.array([[-0.004090321213057993,
                   0.009615388501909157,
                   -0.24223693596921558,
                   0.015504079563927319,
                   -0.02659541428995062,
                   0.018512968977547152,
                   0.00836788544720289,
                   -0.10874776132746002,
                   -0.045863474556415526,
                   -0.010195799916571194,
                   0.09474219315939948,
                   0.03606698737846194,
                   -0.004560110004741025,
                   0.028042417959738858]])


output_1 = layer_output(testV, dense_1_kernel, dense_1_bias)
output_2 = reluFunction(output_1)
output_3 = layer_output(output_2, dense_2_kernel, dense_2_bias)
output_4 = reluFunction(output_3)
```

however, the result of output_4 is very different from what I get using

```
loaded_model = keras.models.load_model("F:\\PyworkingFolder\\WWSHat\\_Data\\alpha0.h5")
predicted = loaded_model(testV)
```

The "predicted" is very close to the ground truth while "output_4" is far away from the ground truth.

I get stuck here and don't know why and failed to find information about how to extract the function I want from the Keras model, I need your help!

Thanks!

Comment: You seem to be missing the last layer ( Dense(1) ) in your calculations.

Comment: Dear @MatiasValdenegro, I tried "dense_0 = f['/model_weights/dense_0/dense_0']" and "dense_3 = f['/model_weights/dense_3/dense_3']", both says "KeyError: 'Unable to open object (component not found)'". On the other hand, the two weight matrices are 14*15 and 15*1, so it seems enough to reproduce the network? Except for that, in another case, the 'output_4' is '0' due to the relu function (become negative before relu), and the model predict 0.48 (ground truth is 0.46), it seems additional layer cannot turn the '0' to '0.48'. Thank you very much for your reply but I cannot get it right

Comment: No, the model in your question has three layers, you are only doing computation for two layers, that is why it does not work. Seems the first layer is the one missing, there is no need to open the HDF5 to get the weights, you can get them directly from the model (with model.get_weights())

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro Thank you very much! Yes I can see using the get_weights, there are 3 layers! I can get it work , thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Dense(14, activation='relu', input_shape=[14]),
    keras.layers.Dense(15, activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dense(1)
])
```

In your model, there are 3 layers, the last dense layer has weight and biases too, you didn't consider them in your calculation.

Comment: Dear @Zabir, thank you very much for your answer, but when I add "dense_3 = f['/model_weights/dense_3/dense_3']" It says "KeyError: 'Unable to open object (component not found)'"  On the other hand, the "dense_1_kernel" is a 14*15 matrix, and the "dense_2_kernel" is a 15*1 matrix, so it seems two matrices make sence?

Comment: You can try `get_weights` or use some visualizer to get the name of the last node, there is definitely one more layer with one neuron, where one multiplication and an addition is happening which you're surely missing.

Comment: Thank you! using `for layer in loaded_model.layers:` and get_weights I can see there are 3 layers and it turn out there is a first layer named 'dense' before 'dense_1' which has a 14*14 weight matrix, I can get it work, thank you!